# Design pattern to sort items in a specified direction using a sorting class

Tags: java, design-patterns

Codebase I am working in has several specialized sorting classes I want to reuse to support sorting in an api.
For instance, a class called SortByHeight takes a list and sorts it in descending order, implementing custom logic before sorting.

I want clients to specify what direction they want to sort in, ascending or descending. The problem is that the SortBy* classes sort items in different orders by default, because that behavior makes sense in the context of the application. So the logic I am looking for is something like

1. Process and sort items with SortBy* class
2. Get the default sort order of the class
3. If it is different than the order specified in the api, reverse the sorted list

My current solution is store pairs of a SortBy* class, along with it's default sort direction in a static Map field of a different class.

Would extending the interface all SortBy* classes implement, by adding a `getDirection` abstract method be a better solution? This would potentially force SortBy* classes to specify the direction they sort in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the interface that all `SortBy*` classes implement is a way better solution. With that, you keep all the implementation details of the `SortBy*` classes in each one of them instead of spreading the knowledge to others.

Imagine that you go with the map and that you Implement a new `SortBy*` class and forget to add it to the map. What will happen? Do you have a default for the default order when you can't find the class in the map? Even if you do, that default might as well be exactly the opposite of what the `SortBy*` class uses.

Having said that, go ahead and change the interface.